# Android: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at FragmentActivity (Support V4 Lib)

Tags: android, android-fragments, indexoutofboundsexception, back-stack

This is the same issue as Issue 22404 hosted on code.google.com (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22404)

To summarize: 4 fragments on the back stack, delete the dialogFragment from the back stack and rotate the phone.

Looks like the line in is: Fragment f = fm.mActive.get(mOps[pos++]);

mOps[pos++] seems to be -1 for some reason.

And I think the reason being is that a dialogFragment got marked for removal and hence got it's state reset. So when reconstructing the backstack mOps[pos++] returns -1 for index.

Any thoughts on that?